# Timer and pthreads (POSIX)

Tags: c++, c, timer, signals

I'm using a pthread to schedule some tasks on my application.
I copied the code from my old C version of the same application and it worked perfectly.
Now I'm coding with C++ and it doesn't work anymore (basically it doesn't trigger the sigevent executing the given function).
All creation and starting functions exit with rc 0, even when i use the timer_gettime.

I simplified a lot the code to narrow down the issue but I could't find it yet:

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <time.h>

int main (void)

{
char Mytimer[5] = "myt";
timer_t Ti_coarse;
Tcreate(Mytimer, &Ti_coarse, 1000, 1000);
while (1)
{

}
return 0;

static int Tcreate( char *name, timer_t *timerID, int expireMS, int intervalMS )
{
   struct sigevent         te;
   struct itimerspec       its;
   struct sigaction        sa;
   int                     sigNo = SIGRTMIN;

   sa.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO;
   sa.sa_sigaction = app;
   sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);
   if (sigaction(sigNo, &sa, NULL) == -1)
   {
       perror("sigaction");
   }

   /* Set and enable alarm */
   te.sigev_notify = SIGEV_SIGNAL;
   te.sigev_signo = sigNo;
   te.sigev_value.sival_ptr = timerID;
   timer_create(CLOCK_REALTIME, &te, timerID);

   its.it_interval.tv_sec = 0;
   its.it_interval.tv_nsec = intervalMS * 1000000;
   its.it_value.tv_sec = 0;
   its.it_value.tv_nsec = expireMS * 1000000;
   timer_settime(*timerID, 0, &its, NULL);

   return 1;
}

static void app(int sig, siginfo_t *si, void *uc)
{
    //do nothing
}
```

I expected to see the "THIS IS THE TIMERS" every second, but I don't get any output.
If I check the expiration time of a 5 mins clock with printf("%d", its.it_value) I always get 299, no matter how much time passed.

Could you possible help me to spot the problem ?

Comment: If you want a signal to be handled by a specific thread, you need to call pthread_sigmask.  Otherwise it might hit any thread.

Comment: Thanks, I missed that point completely.

Answer (score 2):

First, you have not provided a full example that anyone can use to reproduce your problem.  See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

But the code you posted does have one serious problem.  You can't safely use `cout` in a signal handler.  Your signal handler can result in undefined behavior:

```
static void app(int sig, siginfo_t *si, void *uc)
{
    cout << "THIS IS THE TIMER" << endl;
}
```

Per [the POSIX standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_04):

> The following table defines a set of functions that shall be
>   async-signal-safe. Therefore, applications can call them, without
>   restriction, from signal-catching functions. ...
>
> (large table of functions that are safe to call in a signal handler)
>
> Implementations may make other interfaces async-signal-safe. In the
>   presence of signals, all functions defined by this volume of
>   POSIX.1-2008 shall behave as defined when called from or interrupted
>   by a signal-catching function, with the exception that when a signal
>   interrupts an unsafe function or equivalent (such as the processing
>   equivalent to exit() performed after a return from the initial call to
>   main()) and **the signal-catching function calls an unsafe function,
>   the behavior is undefined.**

Using `cout` is not in the table of async-signal-safe functions, so calling it from a signal handler can cause undefined behavior.

Comment: Thanks for the int about the cout, sir. Regarding the code I think I missed the timer_t Ti_coarse declaration and the #include. I'm sorry If I didn't create my example well.

Comment: @Podarce The C `write()` call is async-signal safe.  In C++, `::write( STDERR_FILENO, "THIS IS THE TIMER\n", ::strlen( "THIS IS THE TIMER\n" ) );` is safe.  Note also that it's to `stderr` instead of `stdout` to avoid any interaction with the `stdout` and/or `cout` buffers.

Comment: Thanks sir, I tried using a function on the async-signal safe list, but still no luck getting it to work. I'm thinking about building an Object timer and simplify a bit the code, since I need only 1 second minimum time resolution.