# simulate setTimeout and setInterval of javascript in C

Tags: c, timer, pthreads

I'm trying to implement in C.
setTimeout and setInterval of javascript :

```
setTimeout(function(){ alert("Hello"); }, 3000);
setInterval(function(){ alert("Hello"); }, 3000);
```

i have read some related oveflow question, and 
here my attempt with pthread, i post a minimum example :

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

typedef struct timeCallback_s
{
    int    sec          ;
    void (*cb)(void*)   ;
    int    fInterval     ;
} timeCallback_t ;
static void* timeTimer(void *_t )
{
    timeCallback_t* t = (timeCallback_t*) _t ;

    int   sec         = t->sec ;
    void (*cb)(void*) = t->cb ;
    int   fInterval   = t->fInterval ;

    if ( fInterval==1 ) {
        while(1) {
            sleep(sec);
            (*cb)((void*)&sec);
        }
    }  else  {
        sleep(sec);
        (*cb)((void*)&sec);
    }
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
void timeout_cb(void*_x)
{
    int x = *(int*)_x;
    printf("\n=== CALLBACK %d===\n",x);
}
```

main fuction

```
int main(void)
{
    timeCallback_t timer2;
    timer2.sec       = 1;
    timer2.cb        = timeout_cb ;
    timer2.fInterval = 1 ;

    pthread_t t2;
    pthread_create(&t2, NULL, timeTimer , (void *) &timer2);
    pthread_join(t2, NULL);

    timeCallback_t timer1 ;
    timer1.sec       = 5 ;
    timer1.cb        = timeout_cb ;
    timer1.fInterval = 0 ;

    pthread_t t1;
    pthread_create(&t1, NULL, timeTimer , (void *) &timer1 );
    pthread_join(t1, NULL);

    printf("\n=== End of Program - all threads in ===\n");

    return 0;
}
```

output is a deadlock :

other stack overflow question :

[timer-and-pthreads-posix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45634261/timer-and-pthreads-posix)

[pthread-timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11541733/pthread-timeout)

can you help me ?

solution :

```
pthread_join(t2, NULL);
pthread_join(t1, NULL);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't specify what problem you are having. If it's that `timer1` is never called, it's because you wait for `t2` to exit before creating `t1`, and `t2` never exits.

Move `pthread_join(t2, NULL);` down.

Comment: ok works good, now, move pthread_join(t2,NULL) down, thank you